# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.dlv.dlv.UserResponseInfo for method UserApi.verifyUser

Tags: android

i am using aurae/retrofit-logansquare to parse json in my android retrofit project. 
i am getting following error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.dlv.dlv, PID: 5922
>                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.dlv.dlv.UserResponseInfo
>                         for method UserApi.verifyUser
>                         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
>                         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:706)
>                         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:167)
>                         at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>                         at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
>                         at $Proxy0.verifyUser(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.dlv.dlv.RestApi.verifyUser(RestApi.java:156)
>                         at com.dlv.dlv.DlvActivity$1.onClick(DlvActivity.java:52)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class
>   com.dlv.dlv.UserResponseInfo.
>                       Tried:
>                        * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
>                        * com.github.aurae.retrofit2.LoganSquareConverterFactory
>                         at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:346)
>                         at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:308)
>                         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:704)
>                             ... 16 more

Application terminated.

build gradle (module:app)
`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.3.6'
compile 'com.github.aurae.retrofit2:converter-logansquare:1.4.1'`

Answer (score 8):

One of the reason could be that you are using same name inside @SerializedName() for more than one field.

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's because of sometimes we serialized filed with already existing fields for example

```
 `@SerializedName("user_name")
    @Expose
    private String avartar;`
```

and I already have   private String username;